# upload link is wrong on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I switched my wordpress blog to a different domain.
actually the www changed servers so now the blog.letsfeedme.com should be real - and not direct to www.letsfeedme.com/blog.

I changed: `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` to `http://blog.letsfeedme.com`.

Now, all the media has the wrong URL. 
It looks for the media in 
`http://letsfeedme.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Goat-cheese-log_Daniella.jpg`
instead of:
`http://blog.letsfeedme.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Goat-cheese-log_Daniella.jpg`

Tried:
`upload_url_path`   `http://blog.letsfeedme.com/wp-content/uploads`
and empty...

How can I change it?

(you can have a look at blog.letsfeedme.com for the errors I described)

Comment: there are two option 1. siteurl 2. home  have you changed both?

Comment: yes. `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` in the admin console, are `siteurl` and `home` on the wp_options. all have `http://blog.letsfeedme.com`

Comment: It seems hard coded image url in the code OR post content

Comment: crap - you are right... know any magical plugin that bulk changes it?

Comment: hard coded url in post content?